# Opposite of Substring Function

Tags: r

Is there a way to use the substr() function and specify it to go from right to left instead of left to right?

For example suppose I have this string:

x <- "123456gerger7"

I want to start from the right most position, and take the last 4 characters.

I thought of a way to do this where I reverse the string and then take the first 4 characters:

```
rev_str <- rev(strsplit(x, "")[[1]])
```

reversed_x <- paste(rev_str, collapse = "")
answer = substr(reversed_x, 1,4)

But is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: Note that `stringr::str_sub` as a convenient `-` option: `stringr::str_sub(x, -4, -1)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These solutions only use base R.

We can use `substr` or `substring` with `nchar`. No packages are used.

```
substr(x, nchar(x)-3, nchar(x))
## [1] "ger7"

substring(x, nchar(x)-3)
## [1] "ger7"
```

`sub` would also work.  Replace everything followed by 4 characters followed by end of string with the captured 4 characters.

```
sub(".*(....)$", "\\1", x)
## [1] "ger7"
```

`strcapture` will return a data frame.  Capture the last 4 characters.

```
strcapture("(....)$", x, list(x = character(0)))
##      x
## 1 ger7
```

`read.fwf` also returns a data frame:

```
read.fwf(textConnection(x), c(nchar(x) - 4, 4))
##          V1   V2
## 1 123456ger ger7
```

### Note

```
x <- "123456gerger7"
```

Comment: But it's more fun  to  write  `y <-  rev(somefunction(rev(x))`   :-)